# Jupyter Interactive Widget not executing properly

Tags: user-interface, widget, jupyter-notebook, dashboard, interactive

I am using jupyte notebook

This is the Code

from ipywidgets import interact

## define a function to work with (cubes the number)

def myfunction(arg):
    return arg+1
interact(myfunction, arg=9);

The result showing is 10 instead it should be showing a slider

Showing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DbF6.png)

Instead it show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95JDU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what went wrong with what you did because
there are formatting issues with your post -- you need to indent the
code 4 spaces when you ask the question to make it look right, which
effects the meaning because Python is sensitive to white space.

I modified your text and got it to work for me

```
from ipywidgets import interact

def myfunction(arg): 
    return arg+1 

interact(myfunction, arg=9)
```

Screenshot:

[image]