# How can I use Asynchronous Widgets on jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

## How can I use Asynchronous Widgets on jupyter **lab**?

I'm trying to reproduce [the official Asynchronous Widgets-Example](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html) on jupyter **lab**, but the `await` never continues.

### Setup / reproduction

1. `docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes jupyter/datascience-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''`
2. `firefox 0.0.0.0:8888`
3. create a new python3 notebook
4. create a cell and enter the code below
5. run cell
6. move slider

#### code for the cell

```py
%gui asyncio

import asyncio
def wait_for_change(widget, value):
    future = asyncio.Future()
    def getvalue(change):
        # make the new value available
        future.set_result(change.new)
        widget.unobserve(getvalue, value)
    widget.observe(getvalue, value)
    return future

from ipywidgets import IntSlider
slider = IntSlider()

async def f():
    for i in range(10):
        print('did work %s'%i)
        #x = await asyncio.sleep(1)
        x = await wait_for_change(slider, 'value')
        print('async function continued with value %s'%x)
asyncio.ensure_future(f())
#task = asyncio.create_task(f())
slider
```

### Expected result

The cell outputs

```
did work 0
async function continued with value 1
did work 1
async function continued with value 2
[...]
```

### Actual output

nothing after the first `did work 0`

### Notes

- I'm specifically talking about jupyter **lab** and not about regular jupyter notebooks
- There is no error-message or anything. The expected output just doesn't happen
- The minimal asyncio-example does work in jupyter lab:

```py
import asyncio
async def main():
    print('hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('world')
await main()
```

- when you leave out the `-e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes`, then you get a regular jupyter notebook without jupyter lab and the expected result happens.
- this is **not** a duplicate of [ipywidgets widgets values not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403663/ipywidgets-widgets-values-not-changing) or [Jupyter Interactive Widget not executing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516965/jupyter-interactive-widget-not-executing-properly), because these questions nether include jupyter lab nor asyncio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it works, but jupyter lose print output.
Try this code:

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

out = widgets.Output()

import asyncio
def wait_for_change(widget, value):
    future = asyncio.Future()
    def getvalue(change):
        # make the new value available
        future.set_result(change.new)
        widget.unobserve(getvalue, value)
    widget.observe(getvalue, value)
    return future



from ipywidgets import IntSlider
slider = IntSlider()

# Now the key: the container is displayed (while empty) in the main thread
async def f():
    for i in range(10):
        out.append_stdout('did work %s'%i)
        x = await wait_for_change(slider, 'value')
        out.append_stdout('async function continued with value %s'%x)
asyncio.ensure_future(f())

display(slider)
display(out)
```

You can find more details here: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2567#issuecomment-535971252

Answer (score -1):

I've had luck with jupyter-ui-poll to synchronize widget activity with the Jupyter Python kernal:

https://github.com/Kirill888/jupyter-ui-poll

In particular I used it here:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle/blob/master/jp_doodle/auto_capture.py

Works for me.
Hope that helps!

Comment: I think the underlying mechanism for your example goes in the same direction as the 3rd example for async widgets, which actually does work on jupyter lab: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html#Updating-a-widget-in-the-background