# Overwrite string in for loop in Jupyter Lab Output widget

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, jupyter-lab, jupyter-widget

I am trying to create a sort of survey using Jupyter widgets.
As a bare-bone example, I would like to ask the user if he likes a kind of fruit in a list,
let him check `yes/no` in a `RadioButtons` widget, let him submit his answer, and then ask him if he likes the next fruit.

I would expect something like this:

```
Do you like apples?
* yes
* no
Submit
```

After pressing `Submit`, the `apples` string would be substituted by the next fruit in the list:

```
Do you like oranges?
* yes
* no
Submit
```

What I am getting instead is:

```
Do you like apples?
* yes
* no
Submit
```

And after pressing `Submit`:

```
Do you like apples?Do you like oranges?
* yes
* no
Submit
```

So, the survey question string is not overwritten, but appended to the previous string,
even though I am clearing the `Output` widget with `clear_output` method.

This is what I have achieved so far:

```py
import asyncio

from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets


def create_multipleChoice_widget(description_out, options):
    
    alternativ = widgets.RadioButtons(options=options,
                                      )
    check = widgets.Checkbox(description="Submit")
    
    return widgets.VBox([alternativ, check])


def wait_for_change(widget, value):
    future = asyncio.Future()
    def getvalue(change):
        # make the new value available
        future.set_result(change.new)
        widget.unobserve(getvalue, value)
    widget.observe(getvalue, value)
    return future


fruits = ["apple",
          "orange",
          "kiwi",
          ]


description_out = widgets.Output()
box = create_multipleChoice_widget(description_out, ["yes", "no"])
    


async def f():
    for fruit in fruits:
        
        description = f"Do you like {fruit}s?"
        description_out.append_stdout(description)
        
        alternativ = box.children[0]
        check = box.children[1]
        
        x = await wait_for_change(check, 'value')
        description_out.clear_output()
        #clear_output()
        
asyncio.ensure_future(f())

display(description_out)
display(box)
```

I am not very familiar with `ipywidgets` or `asyncio`.
I managed to write this code after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996358/how-can-i-use-asynchronous-widgets-on-jupyter-lab) and [this](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2487).
As you can see, for the answer submission, I am using a `Check` widget. I tried to use a `Button` widget instead (and it would be my preference), but I did not manage to make it work, since it has no `value` argument.

I appreciate any suggestion!

**Configuration:**

- Jupyter Lab 3.0.5
- ipywidgets 7.6.3
- Python 3.7.9
- Environment installed with Conda, using conda-forge channel, on Ubuntu 18.04