# Overwrite string of Jupyter Output widget

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-widget

How do I overwrite a string that is printed by Jupyter Output widget?

For instance, I know how to do that using simple `print` statements:

```py
from IPython.display import display, clear_output


fruits = ["apple", "orange", "kiwi"]

for fruit in fruits:
    clear_output()
    print(f"Do you like {fruit}s?")
```

Produces what I would expect: the string is printed once for each new `fruit`, overwriting the previous string. In my example, the last printed statement is `Do you like kiwis?`.

But I need to do that with Output widget instead of print statement.
I tried:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets


out = widgets.Output()

for fruit in fruits:
    out.clear_output()
    out.append_stdout(f"Do you like {fruit}s?")

out
```

And I get: `Do you like apples?Do you like oranges?Do you like kiwis?`, which is not what I want!

I also tried placing `out.clear_output()` after the `append_stdout`, and I get a blank line. It seems like in this case each string is actually cancelled before the new one is printed, but also the last string is cancelled!

I appreciate any suggestions!

**Final note**:
This question is a minimalist example from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761354/overwrite-string-in-for-loop-in-jupyter-lab-output-widget), that has not yet received an answer. If you need more context, feel free to also read that question!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this minimalist example, thanks to the [chapter on traitlets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Signatures) of the official `ipywidgets` documentation.

```py
out = widgets.Output()

for fruit in fruits_names:
    with out:
        out.clear_output()
        print(f"Do you like {fruit}s?")
out
```

I still do not perfectly understand why this works as expected, whereas calling `out.clear_output` and `out.append_stdout` outside of a `with` statement did not! Please let me know if you have an explanation!

I am also still interested in my [other bigger question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761354/overwrite-string-in-for-loop-in-jupyter-lab-output-widget).